# MVC5 Creating ComboBox w/ Autocomplete

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, view, combobox

I have a lookup table that has to properties: ID, Name

```
public class Color
{
     public int ID {get;set;}
     public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I'd like to create a ComboBox that let's me select a color or create a new one if the text isn't part of the list.

//Color Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
     ViewBag.ColorID = new SelectList(db.Colors,"ID","Name");
     return View();
}
```

//Create View

```
@model Color

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
<dl>
   <dt>
        @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Name)
   </dt>
   <dd>
        @Html.DropDownList("ColorID", null, "--Select Color --", new {})
   </dd>
</dl>
}
```

At this point I have a dropdown but since it renders as a Select I can't edit the text. Is there anything out of the box with MVC5 that will allow me to create a ComboBox from this point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
 @model Color
 .....

 @using(Html.BeginForm())
 {
    @Html.Hidden("ID")
    <input type="text" name="Name" list="colors" 
                       class="form-control"  id="co" value="@Model.Name" />
    <datalist id="colors">
    @foreach (var item in ViewBag.AttorneyOfficeID)
    {
      <option value="@item.Text" data-id="@item.Value" />
    }
    </datalist>
 }
```

I created a hidden ID to hold the selected option and set it with script on change with this below.

```
<script>
$('#co').on('change', function () {
   var id = $("option").filter("[value='" + $('#co').val() + "']").data("id");
   $("[name='ID']").val(id);
};
</script>
```

This got the job done but I'll leave the question active, as I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This will create a select list (combo box)

`@Html.DropDownList("ColorID", null, "--Select Color --", new { size = "5"})`

But to be more in-depth with my answer, what you are looking for is NOT available out of the box in MVC5.  You need more...
I have used KnockoutJs and AJAX calls to create a type-ahead in the past.